# Multiple Rows for Xml Nodes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml

I have a table `FolderItems` that has a *string* column `fiItem`.  It happens to have Xml in it for rows with `fiEntryType` equal to one of four types.  I have the following query and it *never* finishes when I run it.  I would have thought the `top 10` would have filtered down the SQL rows first BEFORE `cast( . as Xml)` and the `AuditInfo.nodes()` executed.  Is it running forever, because it is casting/querying every row in the `FolderItems` table?

```
SELECT
    pAuthID,
    fiEntryDate,
    fiAuthor,
    Audits.a.value( '@hiType', 'varchar(50)' ) AS [Table],
    Audits.a.value( '@hiIndex', 'varchar(50)' ) AS [Index],
    Audits.a.value( '@dsName', 'varchar(50)' ) AS Field,
    Audits.a.value( '(OldValue/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)' ) AS OldValue,
    Audits.a.value( '(NewValue/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)' ) AS NewValue 
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 10 pAuthID,
        fiEntryDate,
        fiAuthor,
        CAST(fiItem as Xml) AuditInfo
    FROM FolderItems INNER JOIN Profile ON fipKey = pKey
    WHERE figKey = @gKey AND ( fiEntryType = 'dataload' OR fiEntryType = 'created' OR fiEntryType = 'datachange' OR fiEntryType = 'deleted' )
) f 
CROSS APPLY f.AuditInfo.nodes( 'Fields/Field' ) AS Audits(a)
```

I updated query based on another SO question I found to the following (also I need to support filtering on the fields parsed from Xml.

```
SELECT TOP 10
    pAuthID,
    fiEntryDate,
    fiAuthor,
    a.value( '@hiType', 'varchar(100)' ) AS [Table],
    a.value( '@hiIndex', 'varchar(100)' ) AS [Index],
    a.value( '@dsName', 'varchar(100)' ) AS Field,
    a.value( '(OldValue/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)' ) AS OldValue,
    a.value( '(NewValue/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)' ) AS NewValue   
FROM FolderItems INNER JOIN Profile ON fipKey = pKey
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CAST(fiItem as xml) as AuditInfo) x
OUTER APPLY x.AuditInfo.nodes('Fields/Field') as AuditRows(a) 
WHERE 
    figKey = @gKey AND 
    fiEntryDate >= '2020-01-01' AND 
    ( fiEntryType = 'dataload' OR fiEntryType = 'created' OR fiEntryType = 'datachange' OR fiEntryType = 'deleted' ) AND
    a.value( '@dsName', 'varchar(100)' ) = 'date-eff'
```

Comment: your SELECT TOP 10 does not have an ORDER BY ... can you be sure which 10 you're going to get?  Also, have you looked at the query plan? This could give insight into whether `CAST fiItem as Xml` is happening before or after other clauses.

Comment: TOP 10 was just to test out query...would remove or add an order by for paging.  I looked at query plan but I couldn't make heads or tails of it, total weakness of mine.  I'll dig some more.

Comment: You can use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to share the plan so we can see (better than just a screenshot).

Comment: Well, I may have made it worse.  Client is requesting ability to filter by field, table, index, so I needed to include that in the query, which indeed, I think will require parsing all FolderItems.  Here is the plan, and I updated my query a bit in question.  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkkmnoM7P

Comment: You can perhaps convert `a.value( '@dsName' , 'varchar(100)' ) = 'date-eff'` into an XQUERY component of your `nodes` path. Something like `x.AuditInfo.nodes('Fields/Field[@dsName="date-eff"]')` ?